# Python altering my plot data points? [histogram]

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

Attempting to pull data from an excel sheet, apply an equation (in this case `median()`), and create a histogram from that data.

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100000)
absent = pd.read_excel('Absenteeism_at_work.xls')
col = ['Distance from Residence to Work', 'Transportation expense', 'Month of absence', 'Social smoker',
       'Social drinker', 'Education']

# print(absent.loc[:741, col])

plt.title('The Mean')
plt.xlabel('Attribute of Absence')
plt.ylabel('Value')
# x = ['Distance', 'Trans Exp.', 'Month', 'Smoker', 'Drinker', 'Edu.']
x = absent.loc[:741, col].median()
x.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(5, 5))
print(x)
plt.hist(x)

# print(hist)
plt.show() # shows histogram in side-window
```

**Here is the terminal output:**

```
Distance from Residence to Work     26.0
Transportation expense             225.0
Month of absence                     6.0
Social smoker                        0.0
Social drinker                       1.0
Education                            1.0
dtype: float64
```

**and most importantly, the incorrect Histogram:**

[image: Median Histogram based on data above (ignore "The Mean")]

Shouldn't 'Social Smoker' be showing as 0? Also, what is that extra bit of bar to the right of 'Distance from Residence to Work'? Is this proper? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graphs `x.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(5, 5))` and `plt.hist(x)`
getting combined.

**x.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(5, 5)):**

[image]

**plt.hist(x):**

[image]

**Combined:**

[image]

Comment: unrelated, but would you know how to create a scatter plot in roughly the same way?

Comment: plt.scatter(X, y)

Comment: But scatter plot you will need two numerical variables. you have to change your label into some numerical form.